# Printing separate elements in lists in dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, printf, element

I'm having a problem trying a print each element in a list in a dictionary as well as the other items in the dictionary.

```
#dictionaries
bill = {
    "name": "Bill",
    "job": "Policeman",
    "hobbies": ["rugby","music","mischief"],
}
jill = {
    "name": "Jill",
    "job": "Lawyer",
    "hobbies": ["driving","clubbing","basketball"],
}
will = {
    "name": "Will",
    "job": "Builder",
    "hobbies": ["football","cooking","beatboxing"],
}

#list of citizens
citizens = [bill,jill,will]

#print keys with their values for each citizen
def citizen_info(citizens):
    for citizen in citizens:
        for item in citizen:
            print ("%s: " + str(citizen[item])) % (item)
        print ""

#Calling citizen_info
citizen_info(citizens)
```

As you can see, I am trying to print all the items in each dictionary, but when I try to print the separate elements in the lists, it looks like this.

```
job: Policeman

name: Bill

hobbies: ['rugby', 'music', 'mischief']

job: Lawyer

name: Jill

hobbies: ['driving', 'clubbing', 'basketball']

job: Builder

name: Will

hobbies: ['football', 'cooking', 'beatboxing']
```

When I actually hobbies to look like this:

```
hobbies: rugby music mischief
```

Having Googled this problem and searched through on this site, I can find solutions where this problem is solved, but does not work if there is another item in the dictionary that is not a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def citizen_info(citizens):
    for citizen in citizens:
        for item in citizen:
            if type(citizen[item]) is list :
                print ("%s: " + " ".join(citizen[item])) % (item)
            else :
                print ("%s: " + str(citizen[item])) % (item)
        print ""
```

or

```
def citizen_info2(citizens):
    for citizen in citizens:
        for item in citizen:
            if item == "hobbies" :
                print ("%s: " + " ".join(citizen[item])) % (item)
            else :
                print ("%s: " + str(citizen[item])) % (item)
        print ""
```

If you have a list a = ['1', '2', '3'] and want to join the strings inside:

```
" ".join(a)
", ".join(a)
```

Comment: Yep really like the first answer as it is useful for adding future items to the dictionaries, and of course it works. Cheers!

Comment: use `issinstance` not type

Answer (score 1):

You may simply use a ternary condition which would generate string joined by spaces, if the value is of type `list` and the simple string otherwise.

```
def citizen_info(citizens):
    for citizen in citizens:
        for item in citizen:
            print ("%s: " + str(" ".join(citizen[item])) if isinstance(citizen[item], list) else "%s: " + str(citizen[item])) % (item)
        print ""
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def citizen_info(citizens):
    for citizen in citizens:
        for item in citizen:
            if item != 'hobbies':
                print ('{}: {}'.format(item, citizen[item])  # new style string formatting, much easier to read imo
            else:
                print ('{}: {}'.format(item, ' '.join(citizen[item]))
        print ""
```

Using new style string formatting and just handling the `hobbies` key differently .

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the hobbies key separately:

```
#print keys with their values for each citizen
def citizen_info(citizens):
    for citizen in citizens:
        for item in citizen:
            if item != "hobbies":
                print(("%s: " + str(citizen[item])) % (item))
            else:
                print("hobbies", end="")
                for hobby in citizen[item]:
                    print(hobby, end="")
                print("")
    print("")
```

Comment: You mixed `print` usage from Python 2 (where `print` is a statement an a keyword) and from Python 3 (where `print` is a function). Please adjust your answer to either version (Python 2 would be optimal, since it is used in the question).

Comment: There were few other things to fix (especially the first `print` which remained a statement), so I fixed them for you.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you:

```
def citizen_info(citizens):
  for citizen in citizens:  # loop through the citizens
    for key, value in citizen.items():  # get keys and values
      if type(value) is list:  # test if the value is a list
        value = " ".join(value)  # join the list into a string
      print("{}: {}".format(key, value))  # print however you want
```